# Trigger Kubernetes job based on event

Tags: kubernetes

I have a StatefulSet, which contains 3 replicas of my app
I also have a Job, which executes some operations on these apps

Is it possible to trigger Job based on events of my StatefulSet? e.g. scaling or changing configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to trigger Job based on events of my StatefulSet? e.g. scaling or changing configuration?

There is no such built-in function.

Everything in Kubernetes has APIs. You can create an app that:

1. Listen to *Events* for your *StatefulSet*.
2. Interact with Kubernetes API to *create Jobs*.